# How can I customize the edit form of a document set?

Tags: custom-form, document-set, edit-form

I managed to customize the **New Form** for my **Content Types which inherit from Document Set** as follows:

1. put a copy of `15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\newdocset.aspx` in `15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\MY\myNewDocSet.aspx`. In this page, I played with SPUtility to hide and make read only fields and add some dynamic behaviour.
2. powershell `$contentType.NewFormUrl = "_layouts/MY/myNewDocSet.aspx"`.

I would like to do the same for the **Edit Form** of my content types, but don't know from which file to start.

Thank you for your insights,
AllWorkNoPlay

Comment: Our consultant gave me the hint to use JSLink on the Edit form. A drawback is that this Edit form is linked to the library and not to the content type, but I will give it a try. This way I am confident I do not base on the wrong Edit form.

Comment: I ended up having a piece of Javascript code in the Style Library that I included in a custom page MyNewDocSet.aspx, and added as a Content Web Part to the Edit form of the document library. In the Javascript I test the content type like this: `if (typeof(WPQ1FormCtx) != 'undefined' && WPQ1FormCtx != null)
  {
   currentContentType = WPQ1FormCtx.ListData.ContentType;
  }
  else
  {
   currentContentType = WPQ2FormCtx.ListData.ContentType;
  }`

Comment: Have you ever seen a WPQ1FormCtx object? I'm doing some searching to see if WPQ2FormCtx is always going to have that name, and this is one of only 2 search results showing something other than WPQ2FormCtx. The other one is someone speculating as to whether WPQ3FormCtx will ever exist.